# Could not find class XXX referenced in method XXX.YYY

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I'm currently working on an Android application in Maven.  One of the imported dependencies is online, but I also have a modified local version.  I've changed the local version to have a different version number, and have exported it to a jar file.

In my Maven dependency file, I've commented out the original one and added in the below:
compile files('libs/MyFileName-snapshot.jar')

Immediately upon running the application, however, it fails with a bunch of these messages:

11-29 20:53:08.261: E/dalvikvm(5414): Could not find class 'com.xxx.xxx.yyyImpl$2', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.xxxImpl.xxx

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

(Also: I've read the other StackOverflow answers, but they haven't seemed to help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the problem is that version of `com.xxx.xxx.xxxImpl` that is actually being loaded is using an anonymous inner class (which has an synthetic "xxxImpl$2" name), and the davlik classloader cannot find the corresponding class file for the anonymous class.

My guess is that your procedure for "locally modifying" that dependency is incorrect ... but it is impossible to say without some details.  Generally speaking, the best way to download all of the relevant source code (including all dependencies that could be affected) and rebuild them all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Will it be possible to provide more information on what the correct way of modifying the dependency is?  What I did is as follows:  1. Downloaded the source from GitHub   2. Made modifications to .java files  3. Modified version number  4. "mvn package" the new files  5. Added the new .jar to the dependencies

Comment: Just to add: Using the original source code seems to generate the same issue (e.g. after re-packaging the jar, etc).

Comment: Maybe you needed to do a "mvn clean".  It sounds like you have an issue with you are building stuff, but I don't have access to your system to see why the anon class has gone missing.  Anyhow, there should be enough information now for your to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Just tried that, it doesn't seem to have helped.  It looks like "mvn package" is currently only adding ~1k lines to the jar file, but the code has many more.  Is it possible that I'm missing some setting to add the class source into the jar?